# Try, except in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple program that read only two symbols (=, +). I have done the checks using if block like above:

```
x = raw_input("Please answer + or =")
if x == '+':
   print "plus" 
elif x == '=':
   print "equal"
else:
   print "not valid"
```

I want to remove the else and do the check with try, except. 
for example I want something like:

```
try:
   x = raw_input("Please answer + or =")
   if x == '+':
      print "plus" 
   elif x == '=':
      print "equal"
except ....:
   print "not valid"
```

Does anyone can help me? 
Thank you

Comment: I think you are not clear about what `try...except` do. I suggest read about the construct and uses and ask here.

Comment: What operation are you planning to try that may throw an exception?  The given answer shows one possibility.  However, your given code does not have an operation that's particularly susceptible to failure.

Answer (score 1):

```
values = {"+": "plus", "=": "equal"}

x = raw_input("Please answer + or =")

try:
    print values[x]
except KeyError:
    print "not valid"
```

However, I am not sure you should use `try` / `except` here because `if` may be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This reads only + or = and will continue to repeat until + or = is entered.

```
while x != "+" and x != "=":
    if x == "+":
       print "plus" 
    elif x == '=':
       print "equal"
    else:
       print ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def wordify():
    x = raw_input('Please answer + or =: ')

    if x == '+':
        print 'plus'
    elif x == '=':
        print 'equal'
    else:
        print 'Not valid. Please try again.\n'
        wordify()
```

Now you just run the function.

```
In [11]: wordify()
Please answer + or =: 8
Not valid. Please try again.

Please answer + or =: -
Not valid. Please try again.

Please answer + or =: +
plus

In [12]: wordify()
Please answer + or =: *
Not valid. Please try again.

Please answer + or =: =
equal
```

Like everyone else is suggesting, this is not the appropriate case for using `try`/`except`.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a function, you can always raise an error:

```
def somefunction(input):
    try:
        if input == '+':
            return 'plus'
        elif input == '=':
            return 'equal'
        raise ValueError
    except ValueError, e:
        return e.message
```

Comment: That seems like a really odd way of doing things. Also, note that you should use `except ValueError as e:` for any version of Python beyond 2.5.